# How to append Dictionary value in Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary, append

I'm trying to save daily data to a Dictionary. When the user reaches 100% of their daily progress I want to add that day and a "true" value with it into a Dictionary.
The problem is, when I try to add a new Key and Value it overrides the previous one because the current day is coming from the same variable which changes it's data depending on the day.

```
let calendarCurrent = Calendar.current
let currentDate = Date()

monthlyDictionary["\(calendarCurrent.component(.day, from: currentDate))"] = "true"
defaults.set(monthlyDictionary, forKey: "monthlyDictionary")
```

So the Dictionary Key would be a variable equal to the current day and the value would be "true"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted always replaces the contents of a key `monthlyDictionary` with a dictionary. The dictionary you create uses the current day of the month as a key and the value of "true".

Today is 19 January, so if you run that code today, it will create an entry in UserDefaults with the key `monthlyDictionary` and the value of `["19": "true"]`. Tomorrow it will replace the value at the key `monthlyDictionary` with a new dictionary that contains the value `["19": "true"]`

If you want to append a new entry to your dictionary each day, you'll need to read the existing dictionary, append a value, and then re-write it:

```
let calendarCurrent = Calendar.current
let currentDate = Date()

var oldMonthlyDictionary = [AnyHashable:Any]()
oldMonthlyDictionary = defaults.object(forKey: "monthlyDictionary") as? Dictionary else {
   print("dictionary not found. Creating empty dictionary")
}//Add this line

//Add a new key/value pair to your dictionary and re-save it.
oldMonthlyDictionary["\(calendarCurrent.component(.day, from: currentDate))"] = "true"
defaults.set(oldMonthlyDictionary, forKey: "monthlyDictionary")
```

### Edit:

Note that if you run this code more than once in a given calendar day, it will overwrite the previous value for the current day on each subsequent run.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I tried this code but I'm getting the following error : "Value of type 'Any?' has no subscripts"
At the line:  oldMonthlyDictionary["\(calendarCurrent.component(.day, from: currentDate))"] = "true"

Comment: var oldMonthlyDictionary = defaults.object(forKey: "monthlyDictionary") as? Dictionary

Comment: `defaults.object(...)` returns of type `Any` since it does not know the type - you need to type cast to whatever type it should be. From there, you can subscript

Comment: I should know better than to type an answer in an SO thread without compiling it.